# Finding the convex hull of an object in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, convex-hull

I've written this based on the tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html) but I'm unable to obtain the convex hull of the image (I'm using a similar hand image as shown in the tutorial). I get the source and edges output fine but the "Drawings" output which should draw the contour and convex hull lines don't show anything drawn and instead is completely black. Any ideas as to why this could be?

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    cvNamedWindow( "Source", 1 );
    cvNamedWindow( "edges window", 1 );
    cvNamedWindow( "Drawings", 1 );

    IplImage* src = cvLoadImage( "img.jpg", 0 );
    IplImage* edges = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 );

    // Finding edges
    cvThreshold( src, edges, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage();
    CvSeq* first_contour = NULL;

    int Nc = cvFindContours(
        edges,
        storage,
        &first_contour,
        sizeof(CvContour),
        CV_RETR_LIST );

    // Finding convex Hull
    CvMemStorage* hull_storage = cvCreateMemStorage();
    CvSeq* retHulls = NULL;

    for(CvSeq* i = first_contour; i != 0; i = i->h_next){
    // note h_next is next sequence.
    retHulls = cvConvexHull2(first_contour,hull_storage,CV_CLOCKWISE,1);

    }

    // drawing contours and hull
    IplImage* draw = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(edges), 8, 3 );

    for(CvSeq* i = first_contour; i != 0; i = i->h_next){
        cvDrawContours(draw,first_contour,cvScalar(255,0,0,0),cvScalar(255,0,0,0),0,1,8);
        cvDrawContours(draw,retHulls,cvScalar(255,0,0,0),cvScalar(255,0,0,0),0,1,8);

    }

    cvShowImage( "Source", src );
    cvShowImage( "edges window", edges );
    cvShowImage( "Drawings", draw );
    cvWaitKey();

    cvDestroyAllWindows();

    cvReleaseImage( &src );
    cvReleaseImage( &edges );
    cvReleaseImage( &draw );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the following changes:

1. Change parameter from `CV_RETR_LIST` to `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` in `cvFindContours` function.
2. Change `CV_THRESH_BINARY` to `CV_THRESH_OTSU` in `cvThreshold`.

Here's proof (input/output):

[image] [image]

Comment: Hi there, hmm changing it had no impact in my code?, did you try it with my code or your own? - thanks

Comment: cheers that worked for the image uve provided but it doesnt work for something like this? http://i.imgur.com/1nYN7.jpg any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 methods,

1. opencv convex hull

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ShapeDescriptors/hull_demo.cpp

1. cvblob convex hull

https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/

https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/source/browse/trunk/cvBlob/cvblob.h?r=398

CvContourPolygon *cvPolygonContourConvexHull(CvContourPolygon const *p);

HTH