# How to use convexHull function of openCV in iOS objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am someone who is new to openCV and has been trying to use convexhull function in the openCV library for an app (objective-C being used), I need to know what is the input format of function arguments, it's pretty confusing. And does this function return the points in a sequence? Like, if I use addLineToPoint to draw a bezierpath of this hull, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code for you:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
//fill that vector with your points

std::vector<cv::Point> hull;
if (points.size()) {
    cv::convexHull(points, hull);
}

cv::Size size = cv::Size(w, h); 
//some size for the matrix where you will draw your convex hull

cv::Mat hullMask = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
int hull_count = (int)hull.size();
if (hull_count) {
    const cv::Point* hull_pts = &hull[0];
    cv::fillPoly(hullMask, &hull_pts, &hull_count, 1, cv::Scalar(255));
}
```

This code will help you to create convex hull and draw it.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656) you can find complete documentation for that function. It will return points in a sequence according to the "clockwise" argument. By default it will be counter-clockwise.

Comment: thanks for the code and reference, one more thing I would want to ask, what if the points form a concave hull sort of structure, and I want that concave structure, is there any way to do it? more like a concave hull sort of thing? Like if I take a pic of my hand, and I want the points lying on the boundary of my hand, such that joining these points would give the outline of my hand. Can we do it?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813352/finding-the-convex-hull-of-an-object-in-opencv